# Cannot get notifications on records that I follow

Tags: lightning-experience, chatter, notification, follow

I want to follow a record so every time someone posts to the record chatter - I will get notified.

[image]

I cannot get this done.

What I have done so far:

1. `Enable Feed Tracking` for the object with selected fields.
2. `Track Field History` in the object properties.
3. I click follow on the record

I cannot get any notifications even if someone posts to the record

Am I missing some configuration?

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To receive a Lightning notification for posts to records that do not tag you explicitly (`@[Itai Shmida]`), you need to create a [Chatter Stream](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_collab_streamshome.htm) and add the records to it.

Then, you can configure the notification settings on your stream to notify you on every post. (Image below stolen from release notes).

[image]

You can also [add records to Streams from the Follow button](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_collab_followtostream.htm) once the stream is created.

Comment: for this to work - do I need to create a stream for each record to follow?

Comment: No, you can add multiple records to a stream.

Comment: I can see now, and each user needs to create his own stream, and there is a limit of 25 records on a stream. This is really a bummer. I want to base the communication between my community users and internal users on the records posts, but an internal user is not notified if the community user wrote some message on the record. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: As far as explicit notifications go, no, not unless you use automation to post the messages and ensure they include an explicit username ping to the user. Otherwise, the user *will* see the update in their Chatter feed, but they won't get a red notification marker.

Comment: thank you very much, this is really helpful, and the stream solution is not perfect, but good enough

Comment: I'm with you on that. My users also want a more flexible, automated system for doing notifications!

Comment: The new Notifications released in Summer '19 might help produce a more flexible notification approach, but I've had issues with them duplicating when process builder fires multiple times.